# Overwritten new standard button not working in lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

we have a custom lightning component overwritting our new Event standard button.

When trying on org it's working fine but if we try to call it from our custom lightning community it's not working and proceeding with its standard behaviour (displays new Event record creation popup)

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">
    <h1>test text</h1>
</aura:component>
```

Is there something we're missing? Do we need to add another interface for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation itself- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:actionOverride/documentation, it states that

> this interface has no effect except when used within Lightning
>   Experience and Salesforce1.

Which is why it isn't working in communities.

[image]